# SwitfUI ForEach Index

Tags: foreach, swiftui

I want to display an ordered List, have this code:

```
List {
    var i = 1
    ForEach(definitions, id: \.self) { definition in
        Text("\(i). \(definition)")
        // a little bit ugly
        let _ = i += 1
    }
}
```

Is there nicer option?

Comment: yes there is. Look-up enumerated or indices or ForEach(0..<definitions.count) { i in  ..} , just to name a few alternatives.
For the `ordered` part, look-up some form of `.sorted(...)`

Comment: Is your definitions array static or dynamic?

Comment: Using `ForEach(Array(zip(definitions, definitions.indices)), id: \.0)` is a great way to safely get your indices and allow for moves, insertions or deletions in your list. Just make sure `definitions` is `Identifiable`.

Answer (score 0):

```
List {
    ForEach(definitions.indices, id: \.self) { i in
        Text("\(i). \(definitions[i])")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up with this version. Edit. OK, I can't do linebreaks in comments?